# In Shell Script i have implemented argument as Key Value pair, if any of the value is not provided, it takes key as the vallue

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sh

I have a script such that it accepts  pairs
eg `test.sh --arg1 "value1" --arg2 "value2"`

```
while :; do
  case "$1" in
    --arg1)
      if [ "$2" ]; then
        name=$2
        shift
      fi;;
    --arg2)
      if [ "$2" ]; then
        lastname=$2
        shift
      fi;;
   -?*)
      die "ERROR: Unknown option: $1";;
    *)
      break
  esac
  shift
done
```

In Jenkins, if any of the optional field is not available, the value will be taken as the key

```
sh test.sh --arg1 ${arg1} --arg2 ${arg2}
```

If `${arg1}` doesn't have any value it takes `-arg2` as value which is wrong.
How can I correct it?

Comment: Your loop wouldn't handle `test.sh --arg1 --arg2 "value2"` or `test.sh --arg1 "" --arg2 "value2"` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the variable expansions.

```
sh test.sh --arg1 "${arg1}" --arg2 "${arg2}"
```

Comment: If the code recognizes "" as being undefined that should handle it nicely. If an empty string is a valid "defined" value it may require some logic edits. Amar? Will that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want if someone leaves a value with just they key , it should throw an error.

sh test.sh --arg1 --arg2 somevalue

arg1 is not passed.

Comment: The UNIX philosophy is to avoid guessing at user intent. What if they mean for `--arg2` to be arg1's value? It's possible.